# How do I convert a "tbl_df" "tbl" "data.frame" object to a "tbl_Redshift" "tbl_dbi" "tbl_sql" "tbl_lazy" "tbl" object for uploading?

Tags: r, dplyr, amazon-redshift, dbi, dbplyr

I am very new to using servers for data analysis, and I am completely baffled by what a "tbl_df""tbl""data.frame" object, and "tbl_Redshift" "tbl_dbi" "tbl_sql" "tbl_lazy" "tbl" is in R? I know that something related to the Redshift server and tbl-lazy tables but that's it.

I have been following on a previous analyst's work, and I have used collect() to pull a bunch of data onto the local machine, doing some transformation before trying to upload it back to the server. However, I cannot upload the data using compute() for some reason, and I believe the reason is because the object itself became "tbl_df""tbl""data.frame" from "tbl_Redshift" "tbl_dbi" "tbl_sql" "tbl_lazy" "tbl".

Is there a way to transform this back so I can upload it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `mtcars` (a base R sample dataset) is class `"data.frame"`. The tidyverse (and specifically `tibble` package) has an extension to that for the purpose of changing how the frame is rendered on the console (among a few other things). In order to do that, it prepends other classes to that, namely `"tbl_df"` and `"tbl"`. Those classes are used for R's S3 method dispatch. Classes like `"tbl_Redshift"` are likely created using `dbplyr` or similar mechanisms where it looks to be a frame-like object but is not (yet) loaded fully into R's memory. All `tbl_*` other than `tbl_df` are for "lazy" ops, iiuc

Comment: You likely need to "realize" the computed data; this can be done by calling `collect(obj)` on the object that is `"tbl_*"` and not `"tbl_df"`. Note that this will pull all data from the lazy connection into R's memory; this might be small, but if you have a large amount of data, this might take time and/or exhaust local resources (in the "big data" theme).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's begin by ensuring the core concepts are clear:

- `tbl_df`, `tbl`, and `data.frame` are all local objects where the data exist in local R memory.
- `tbl_Redshift`, `tbl_dbi`, and `tbl_sql` are all remote objects where the data exists in the database and R has a pointer/query/connection to the database in local R memory.

The `collect` command retrieves data from a remote database into local R memory. Hence it converts an object of type `tbl_Redshift`, `tbl_dbi`, or `tbl_sql` into an object of type `tbl_df`, `tbl`, 0r `data.frame`.

The `compute` command works for remote objects (`tbl_Redshift`, `tbl_dbi`, or `tbl_sql`) and saves an temporary/intermediate stage of a calculation to the database, creating a new remote object. This helps reduce additional computation. It can not be used to copy data from local R memory.

Put another way:

- `collect` : remote data input -> local data output
- `compute` : remote data input -> remote date output

It sounds like what you need is : local data input -> remote data output.

For this, there are two broad options:

1. Redesign your code to avoid `collect`. If the data is never copied from the server into local R memory then you never have to transfer it back.
2. Use a function designed for copying data to a server. I use the `DBI::dbWriteTable` command for this purpose. Example function below.

```
copy_from_r_to_sql <- function(db_conn, db, schema, sql_table_name, r_table_name) {
  DBI::dbWriteTable(
    db_conn,
    DBI::Id(
      catalog = db,
      schema = schema,
      table = sql_table_name
    ),
    r_table_name
  )
}
```

(This is a cut down version of one of my dbplyr helpers [here](https://github.com/simon-anasta/dbplyr_helpers/blob/master/dbplyr_helper_functions.R))

Comment: Thank you so much Simon, that gives a much clearer picture of what is going on :)